# Grab all text from certain class, only if it is a child of another class

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I'm trying to extract all of the "jobs" someone has on a LinkedIn profile (for educational purposes only), but I cannot find the right approach using BeautifulSoup.

I notice that the header for Jobs are nested in the following way:

```
<div class="pv-entity__company-details">
  <div class="pv-entity__company-summary-info">
    <h3 class="t-16 t-black t-bold">
      <span class="visually-hidden">Company Name</span>
      <span>Morgan Stanley</span>
    </h3>
        <h4 class="t-14 t-black t-normal">
          <span class="visually-hidden">Total Duration</span>
          <span>2 yrs 7 mos</span>
        </h4>
  </div>
</div>
```

I'm trying to extract the text "Morgan Stanley" from every `t-16 t-black t-bold` BUT ONLY if it is under the `pv-entity__company-summary-info` div.

Trying something like this:

```
all_jobs = ', '.join(sel.xpath('//*[contains(@class, "t-16 t-black t-bold")]/text()').extract())
```

Gives too much spurious text because there are lots of objects that contain the `t-16 t-black t-bold` class that are not under the   `pv-entity__company-summary-info` class.

Any thoughts?

Comment: _but I cannot figure out how to encode the "under" concept._ Then what you need is a guide to XPath, no?

Comment: In css: `.pv-entity__company-summary-info h3 span + span`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You didn't paste too much html, but does this selector work:

```py
all_jobs = ', '.join(sel.xpath('//*div[class="pv-entity__company-summary-info"]h3/span[text()]').extract())
# if you want just second span in the html above
all_jobs = ', '.join(sel.xpath('//*div[class="pv-entity__company-summary-info"]h3/span[2][text()]').extract())
```

[xpath cheatsheet](https://devhints.io/xpath)

Comment: Your second xpath is functionally equivalent to the one I specified.  It doesn't work because it grabs all h3 tags on the entire page (which is more than just the job postings).  I specifically want to grab h3 tags that are under the "pv-entity__company-summary-info" class

Comment: @Parseltongue I updated answer. But if you want a better answer you have to provide more information (i.e. more html).

Comment: This is perfect!  Thanks